# Wampserver can't get Named Virtual hosts to work

Tags: windows, apache, wampserver

Using wampserver I can't get named virtual hosts to work.  I've edited the httpd.conf to use the

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I've added the domain to my system32/driver/etc/hosts file.  I've edited the httpd-vhosts.conf file and everything seems to work except now localhost is unavailable.  The domain I setup (test123.com) works fine, hitting 127.0.0.1 works fine, but hitting localhost hangs. There is nothing relevant in the error logs and no mention of it in the access logs.  Here is how I have edited httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Tells Apache to serve the default WAMP Server page to "localhost"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost 
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test123.com
    ServerAlias *.test123
    # Folder where the files live
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/html/test123"
    # A few helpful settings...
    <Directory "D:/Projects/html/test123">
        Options FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  In httpd.conf I had to change

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen *:80
```